# How to execute (via ant) a set of sql files with mysql command line

Tags: mysql, file, ant, set, execute

I want to execute all sql files which resistes in a given directory.
The call i want to make is something like this:

```
mysql --host=dbbackend --user=stack --password=overflow dbname -e 'source file1.sql'
```

This can be expressed as:

```
  <apply executable="mysql" dir="." failonerror="true">
      <arg value="--host=dbbackend"></arg>
      <arg value="--user=stack"></arg>
      <arg value="--password=overflow"></arg>
      <arg value="mydbname"></arg>
      <arg value="--e source dummy.sql"></arg>
      <fileset dir="${db.dump.location.data}" casesensitive="no" description="take all sql files">
          <patternset>
              <include name="**/*.sql" />
          </patternset>
      </fileset>
  </apply>
```

If i have 3 sql files in that dir, then dummy.sql is called 3 times. So far so good. Is there a placeholder available to change this line:

```
      <arg value="--e source dummy.sql"></arg>
```

into:

```
      <arg value="--e source ${unknown.placeholder.name}"></arg>
```

If there is a placeholder, then i want to use it for the "input" attribute of the "apply" tag (and remove the argument "-e").

There is a "srcfile" tag available for the "apply" element, but i can not call this (does not work):

```
      <arg value="--e source"></arg>
      <srcfile/>
```

Do you have suggestions on how to do it with native ant declaration?
Is it possilbe to build a workaround using antcall+fileset (+placeholder)?

The noobish workaround is to iterate via fileset and create a temp sql file with references to the sql files. As a last step: call it static via "-e". But that is a workaround that i want to remove (by this question).

PS: I do not want to use ant-contrib features.

Comment: Little off-topic, since you got your answer. You can write `<arg value=".." />`, you don't have to use the `</arg>`, just you write it with a `/>`. Oh yeah,... and accept an answer in case you have gotten yours.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the [ant sql task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html), which is designed to do exactly what you want to do?

Else, you may use the `srcfile` nested element:

```
<apply ... parallel="false">
  <...>
  <arg value="--e source" />
  <srcfile/>
  <fileset ...></fileset>
</apply>
```

There is a complete example on the [manual page of the apply task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html).